# Provide execute privileges to User for particular pipeline-Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

To be short and small I am looking for a procedure or plugin so that one user can has ownership of only his one and only one pipeline.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can assign and manage roles using Jenkins. Please navigate to Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Manage and Assign Roles.

If you do not see the Manage and Assign Roles option please install the "Role-based authorization strategy" plugin.

Now you can create the Project Roles and assign it to the specific Users/Groups.

More information onto how to use role based authorization could be [found here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin).